# Hide/Disable Edit button based on column's Values in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a column that has 2 Categories, Done and Pending. I would like to Hide/Disable edit button once the user selects an item and if that item has a Status column of "Pending".

I would like to know how can this be done, whether in visual studio 2010 or ECMA Scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but if someone still needs the answer:
Create a custom action in visual studio like this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408060(v=office.14).aspx

This hides the button you want, now you can set a condition via enabledscript parameter to choose in which case the button should be hidden:

Just add this code after `</CommandUIDefinitions>`

```
<CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
        Command="HideEditRibbon"
        CommandAction="javascript:return true;" EnabledScript="javascript:checkIfNeedsToBeHidden();" />
</CommandUIHandlers>
<CustomAction Id="yourJsReference" Location="ScriptLink" ScriptSrc="yourJsFile.js"></CustomAction>
```

If you need this in List-Ribbon, Edit and DisplayForm, you need to make 3 Custom Actions and change the Location-Part and maybe your js-code.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use an out of the box edit form then you're not going to do this with server side code; you'd need an entirely custom edit form to do that.

This means using Javascript on the edit page, which is fragile, and doesn't prevent users from saving the data if they know what they're doing.

The input field for every column will have a 'title' attribute with the column name.  JQuery can find the element with title='column name' rather easily, so that's how you'll know if you need to hide the save button.  The save button isn't quite as easy to get to.  You could try getting the input with type=button and value=save.

If it's important to have actual security around this, so that no matter what someone can't edit an item in this state then you can use an event receiver on the ItemUpdating event.  Just check the properties of the item and use the properties.Cancel = true; (or something like that) so that even if they disable your JavaScript and save the event anyway, it won't get saved.  If you need help adding an event receiver or getting it working just ask.

Edit:  In your comment that you say you just want to prevent access to the edit form entirely under certain conditions.  For that, I'd make a new webpart/user control and add it to the edit page.  In that section you can fetch the appropriate item (the ID of the item will be a query parameter) and see if the page should be 'viewable'.  If not, then you can redirect to another page.

Another addition to the above would be attempting to edit the list view such that there is no edit link for certain items.  This would be substantially harder, and I doubt it would even be possible (practically) with out of the box webparts.  You would need to have an entirely custom list view page in order to control which items have links to an edit page.  (Others feel free to correct me here.)

Comment: Thanks servy for your reply, The javascript solution sounds good but i would prefer that users can't even get to the edit form. I would like to know more about on doing this with the event reciever, i would like to know more about this, I'm still new on development in sharepoint using visual studio 2010.

Comment: Ahh.  Well, you're not going to do that with an event receiver.  You could prevent users from ever committing any of their changes with one, but you couldn't prevent them from accessing the page with one.